# How to compile a program into different projects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compilation

Let us say that: I have a project, this project uses a references (office2016.dll).
in my project I have a c# classes that access  these references and works fine.

Now I want to compile the same code but by using different references, this time (office2012.dll).
note that (office2016.dll  & office2012.dll) are sharing the same methods and types that I used in my c# code.
but I want to publish different (EXE) for each product. one for office 2016, and another for office 2012.

**Is it possible to compile the same c# code on different references (dll)?**

One solution is to copy my c# code in a new project and then add the other (office2012.dll) and then recompile again, it works and fine but I would n't like to do that manually because I work every day and it requires many efforts and concentrations and of course extra time, because really I don't believe on copy/paste code, this is actually a tedious work!

Comment: You can use hack with links to files. Create two projects: one contains actual code and references to, say, office2016.dll. But the second one has only links to files from your first project and references office2012.dll. To make a link you need to drag files from the first project with pressed _Alt_ button.

Comment: How to add links to a project, I tried but there is no way to add a links

Comment: You can drag from the first project with pressed _Alt_ button. Or use _Add Existing Item_. Add button has dropdown that allows to select _Add As Link_

Comment: I added my c# classes, but there is a compile error, that it could not access the references in the code.  because as I said in my c# classes I uses a reference to office2016.dll  and by adding the c# classes to another new project it can't access the old project references

Comment: 1. The second project should have the same references as the first one but office2016.dll. If this does not work, then classes in office2016.dll and office2012.dll are in the different namespace. Workaround: conditional compilation.

Comment: You can try Post-build event command line. (I wasn't able to do that myself but I think there should be some ways to do the trick) take a look, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create copies of the project file (the `.csproj`) in the **same folder**, then include the copied project(s) in your solution. You can then pick the correct references for each project. Make sure to go to the project properties and choose a custom assembly name and/or output folder for each project (ie. `myoffice2012app.exe` and/or `bin/Release2012`).

Any code file you add *afterwards* will have to be included in each copy, but this is simplified by selecting "show all files":

[image]

right-clicking the new files and selecting "Include In Project" - but besides having to add each *new* code file to each project separately, you can build the solution as often as you want without further steps needed.

Comment: I don't like to use any code copy. This is not a concrete mechanism, it is not efficient enough as I explained above!

Comment: You don't copy code - you copy the project files, and you include the _same code files_ in each project. Every line of code you type will appear in all project files simultaneously and you can compile all at once.